# Wordpress logo cutting out content in mobile and minimized windows

Tags: css, wordpress

I am currently working on a landing page using the leadinjection theme on Wordpress. The landing page is functioning just fine, but I can't seem to edit the content to fit minimized browsers and mobile. Here are pictures of the issue:

This is the landing page on a full browser, and no content is being covered by the header logo:

[image]

As you can see the logo header is cutting off the content as depicted by the blue arrows in a minimized browser and mobile:

[image]

Thank you all for your help :)

C

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Please post some code to at least a link to your website so we can debug and help you

Comment: `img {width: 100%; height: auto;}` These rules will keep any image responsive and scale proportionally relative to the inherit width and height of the parent element.

Comment: Hi everyone! Thank you so much for the prompt responses! Here is the code we are working with for reference

Comment: [vc_row full_width="stretch_row" full_height="yes" parallax="content-moving" parallax_image="16" css=".vc_custom_1461955939930{background-color: #595959 !important;}"][vc_column width="1/2" css=".vc_custom_1461964396030{margin-bottom: 300px !important;}"][leadinjection_image image="41"][/leadinjection_image][vc_custom_heading text="What's your location strategy?" font_container="tag:h6|font_size:50|text_align:left|color:%23ffffff" use_theme_fonts="yes" css=".vc_custom_1462128457287{padding-top: 60px !important;padding-bottom: 20px !important;}"

Comment: As well as the link to the website : ) www.google.t-sciences.com

Comment: @ChristiannaClark have you tried adding a little padding to the `.vc_parallax` element? There are a few dynamic inline styles for this element, you will notice them adjusting accordingly when you resize the browser, but if you declare a `padding-top` rule it'll give you some breathing room and scale more gracefully. But don't avoid using `@media` queries when you need them either.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, thank you for the advice! Fixed my issue!